# Tiny people have to cross a city and get lost in a milk factory

Tags: identify-this-movie

I was thinking about the name of a *live-action* movie, in which tiny people appear who have to cross the city, and get lost in a milk factory.

How is it called? The only thing I can find is an animated movie.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Sounds like [**The Borrowers**](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0118755/):

> A secret family of four-inch people living inside the walls of a house must save their home from an evil real estate developer.

[Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Borrowers_%281997_film%29) confirms that there are scenes in a milk factory.

[image: Borrowers]

[[Watch Trailer](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=lgZQ8gyUlwI)]

Comment: Wow, you are great!! Thank you two thousands times!

Comment: For those interested, Ghibli's [Arrietty](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrietty) is also based on the same novel.

Comment: @coleopterist I was _about_ to suggest that, but you beat me to it. By three years...